# Java Apache HTTP 401 response returned with correct credentials

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to hit a REST API link using Apache HttpClient but I keep getting a 401 error returned. I can login when I go to the URL in browser, after being prompted for a password. The code I'm using is below:

```
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(creds.get(0), creds.get(1));
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        authCache.put(new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), "https"), new BasicScheme());

        BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        context.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, provider);
        context.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler());
        client.setCredentialsProvider(provider);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            // response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
            response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri), context);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("Error running authenticated get request: " + e);
        }
```

I'm using HttpClient 4.2.3 and unfortunately I'm not able to upgrade this.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT:** turns out I need to supply the certificate, like using -cacert in curl, however I can't find an example of this!

Comment: Could you please provide what creds is ? I assume a ArrayList but let's see how you put data in it.

Comment: It's a List passed in as a parameter of the method and I can confirm that the correct username and password is there when I step through the code.

Comment: What API are you trying to reach ? Is it a public one ?

Comment: Not public unfortunately, and when I try to copy and paste the uri generated into the browser it doesn't work, but typing the exact same thing out in the browser does.

Comment: Does the API have any documentation concerning authentication/authorization ? You probably haven't understood something there. Maybe try achieving a successful GET on Postman first if you're familiar with it.

Comment: So I can execute the request correctly using wget from the console, passing the same username and password and using the same url, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong to do with the java side of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to provide a certificate maybe this can help:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

I think that example complies with 4.2.3 .